# ColResizeable Plugin - not Supporting Tables in Modal/Pop up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, jquery-plugins

I'm facing this issue with Angular 5 Project where the tables inside the modal window do have the css added for ColResizeable, but not able resize the columns.

The tables in normal pages works fine but not for Modals,
I'm using a normal Modal window pop up a Angular components as below,

parent.html

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalShowUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalShowUser">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-wide" role="document">
        <app-modal-user [inputUsers]="users"></app-modal-user-search> ==> angular component which shows table 
      </div>
    </div>
```

app-modal-user.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('table').colResizable();
  }
```

Wondering if this was already raised or faced by other users ?

Plugin : https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable